# I have a web design layout- how do I translate it into html?

Tags: html

I have a web design layout but don't know how to translate it into html/CSS so that it looks exactly like the images of my layout.

Comment: Buy books and learn HTML and CSS. Or Hire a web designer.

Comment: Learn HTML, CSS, and Javascript. If you have specific questions, post them here.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Adobe Photoshop. Use the slice tool to slice up your image/layout and then go to file-> Save for Web & Devices and your html/CSS code will be generated automatically

Comment: very old way....even @luke you should use div's rather than tables.Avoid tables.

Comment: I didn't downvote you, I actually upvoted you because what you are saying is correct, however the fact that you are correct doesn't mean it's a good idea. The problem with those tools are that they are not accurate and that the HTML that they provide is unmaintainable. Generally, web designers don't do this kind of things.

Comment: but it is an easy beginner way to make a layout

Comment: Jumping off a cliff is an easy beginner way to travel very quickly. It doesn't mean anybody should think about doing it.